# Questions on Limit with Logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

I have the following given as an answer to a questions, but I don't understand how I get $1+ \log n$ in the second step.  I think I am to use L'Hospital's, but deriving the logarithm is $1/(n\ln(b))$, so I don't know why I'm keeping $\log(n)$.  I know it's probably something basic, but what am I missing about that step?

[image]

Comment: consider the product rule applied to $x\log(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second step is the application of l'Hopital Rule and precisely the derivative of the denominator

$$(x\log x)'=x(\log x)'+(x)'\cdot\log x=x\frac1x+1\cdot \log x=1+\log x$$

For a direct approch without l'Hopital, note that for $x\to \infty$ $\forall a>0$

$$\frac{x^a}{\log x}\to +\infty$$

indeed set $x=e^y\to +\infty$ with $y\to +\infty$

$$\frac{x^a}{\log x}=\frac{e^{ay}}{y}\to+\infty$$

Comment: so, why does $(logx)'$ evaluate to $1/x$ and not $1/(n∗ln(b))$?

Comment: @NikNik $\log$ without any other indication is to be intended as natural logarithm $\ln$

Answer (score 1):

You can also rewrite it as:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{1,001}}{n \log{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{0,001}}{\log{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{n^{-0,999}}{0,001}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{0,001}}{0,001} = \infty$$
which might be a little clearer.